# 404 Error on Spring Boot Hibernate Postgres application

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a Spring Boot Hibernate Postgres application: https://github.com/TRahulSam1997/hibernate-spring-postgresql-project

Everything builds, and the application runs, but when I make any API calls, I get a 404 error. I cannot figure out what I've done wrong.

`application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
server.servlet.context-path=/api/v1/
```

Main: `HibernateSpringPostgresProjectApplication.java`

```
package com.example.HibernateSpringPostgreSQLProject;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateSpringPostgresProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateSpringPostgresProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Model: `Users.java`

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    private long userId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String userName;
    private String email;

    public Users() {
//        super();
    }

    public Users(String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String email) {
//        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    //    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_name", nullable = false)
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Column(name = "email_address", nullable = false)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [userId=" + userId + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", userName=" + userName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }
}
```

Controller: `UsersController`

```
package controller;

import exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import model.Users;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import repository.UsersRepository;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
//@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    // get users
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
        return this.usersRepository.findAll();
    }

    // get user by id
    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Users> getUserById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long userId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Users user = usersRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User with this id not found:: " + userId));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(user);
    }

    // save user
    @PostMapping("/users")
    public Users createUser(@Validated @RequestBody Users user) {
        return usersRepository.save(user);
    }

    // update user
    @PutMapping("/users/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Users> updateUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long userId,
                                            @Validated @RequestBody Users userDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Users user = usersRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User with this id not found:: " + userId));

        user.setEmail(userDetails.getEmail());
        user.setFirstName(userDetails.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(userDetails.getLastName());

        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.usersRepository.save(user));
    }

    //delete user
    @DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    public Map<String, Boolean> deleteUser(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long userId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Users user = usersRepository.findById(userId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User with this id not found:: " + userId));

        this.usersRepository.delete(user);

        Map<String, Boolean> response = new HashMap<>();
        response.put("deleted", Boolean.TRUE);

        return response;
    }

}
```

JpaRepository: `UsersRepository`

```
package repository;

import model.Users;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {

}
```

When I make a POST request through Postman, I get the following error:

POST Body:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe",
    "userName": "JohnDoe",
    "email": "john@johndoe.com"
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-04-19T00:31:39.464+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/api/v1/users"
}
```

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: "@RequestMapping" is commented , if you want to make calls , try with path "/users" , also if you want to make calls as described on your request "/api/v1/users", uncomment "@RequestMapping" and add the following path  "/api/v1"

Answer (score 1):

You're requesting the api with `/api/v1/users` as said in the error ,
while in the controller method and it is only `@GetMapping "/users"` so try to add `/api/v1` on the controller level e.g `@RequestMapping("/api/v1")`

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment the following line:

```
//@RequestMapping("/v1")
```

And send post request to /v1/users/

If you want to add "api" to url just change to this:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
```

And remember to change url in postman to /api/v1/users

Answer (score 0):

application.properties

```
server.servlet.context-path=/api/v1/
```

method url path

```
  v1/users
```

Get Url

```
/api/v1/v1/users
```